# Determinants associated with Stern's diatomic sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, determinants

Consider the so-called *Stern's triangle* ([refer to these slides by R. Stanley](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/transparencies/stern-ml.pdf)), we denote here by $a_n(k)$. In an article [Some linear recurrences motivated by Stern’s diatomic array](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.04647.pdf), Stanley provided the generating functional format
$$\sum_{k\geq0}a_n(k)x^k=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+x^{2^i}+x^{2\cdot2^i}).$$
The author also studied power sums, such as,
$$\pmb{v}_{n,r}:=\sum_{k\geq0}a_n(k)^r.$$
At present, starting with the recurrences satisfied by Stern's sequence, $a_n(k)$; that is, $a_n(2k+1)=a_{n-1}(k)$ and $a_n(2k)=a_{n-1}(k)+a_{n-1}(k+1)$, one may compute a system of recursive equations for $\pmb{v}_{n,r}$. This leads to some matrices (my interest is in their determinants). An example may be found in [Proof of a conjecture of Stanley about Stern's array](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.06301.pdf) (page 2), a follow up paper by D. Speyer. For another example look back into [the 2nd paper mentioned above](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.04647.pdf) (page 6).

So, I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Suppose $M(r)$ is the matrix, of size $(r+1)\times(r+1)$, of entries
> $$M_{i,j}(r)=\binom{i}j+\binom{2r-i}{j-i}+\binom{2r-i}j-t_{i,j} \qquad 0\leq i,j\leq r$$
> where $t_{i,j}=0$ except for the last column $t_{i,r}=\binom{2r-i}r$. Is the following true?
> $$\det M(r)=(-1)^{\delta_r}\,\,2^{\lfloor \frac{r+3}3\rfloor}$$
> with $\delta_r$ a period-$12$ sequence in the pattern $[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0]$. Here $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the *floor function*.

Comment: In the first display, is $x_k$ supposed to be $x^k$?

Comment: Oh, yes. I've corrected that now. Thank you.

Comment: How does the question relate to the $a_n(k)$?

Comment: @BrianHopkins: I've added a couple of lines to give directions in this regard.